# Where clause not working in a partitioned table from Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, partition

I'd like to know why My SQL is not working to a partitioned table. Also what should be the correct query?

[Here is the sample table structure I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEOW0.png)

Also, Below is my query:

```
**SELECt * from `TestProj.table_name`
where business_date = '2021-01-31'
and item = '102064962'**
```

;

Note that the table partitioned per day by the business_date column.

The query has no result. But looking into the actual table it should show some results.

The query below works:

```
 **SELECt * from `TestProj.table_name`
 where business_date = '2021-01-31';  **
```

Comment: Probably the first query has no results because the business_date of the item is different from the date entered

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[To take advantage of partitions you might want to try structuring your query like](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables):

```
WITH DATA_FROM_PARTITIONS AS(
SELECT * 
FROM `TestProj.table_name`
WHERE
business_date BETWEEN DATE('2021-01-31')
AND DATE('2021-02-01')),
SELECT * 
FROM DATA_FROM_PARTIONS 
WHERE item = '102064962'
AND business_date = DATE('2021-01-31');
```

The first AS keyword limits the partitions that BQ looks through which reduces query time and costs. If that isn't important to you, you can try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM
`TestProj.table_name`
WHERE
business_date = DATE('2021-01-31')
AND item = '102064962'
```